# Is there a way to remove all items from squad members, or exchange items between squad members?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

Is there a way to remove all items from squad members, or easily exchange items between squad members?  It can be obnoxious to try and remember which items you've placed on which squad member, especially if you have many recruits and only a few medkits/scopes.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

No, this is a relatively common interface complaint - I've seen it several times in various forums.  If you want to find a particular item, you've got to dig through all your soldiers to find it.

From experience, wounded soldiers return their items to the central pool while they are on medical leave, and then I believe they'll try to reequip when they come back to active duty.  However, soldiers on Psi training do not do the same.  You'll have to go to the barracks and manually unequip their stuff.  (This is a major pain if you don't realize this before you've accepted a mission, although you can still back out and go to the barracks, and then back to mission control when finished)

For certain "cheap" items like medkits, I suggest overproducing and just hand them out like candy.  With more expensive stuff like high-end weapons and armor, I'll tend to completely strip a soldier (including resetting their equipment back to the default grenade) if I'm taking them out of the active rotation - that way, I can tell at a glance by their weapon and armor in relation to other soldiers whether or not they're combat-ready and/or are potentially holding a key item.

Comment: +1 Keeping one item per soldier on hand is a good way to avoid this problem. Also, from my experience, wounded soldiers don't always unequip an item if there are enough of it to go around. (I'm not entirely sure how the game makes that decision, though.)

Comment: In the classic game at least in soldier list you did see who's assigned to Skyranger.

Comment: Yep, this is a blunder. The original game only let you edit your soldiers before the mission and that was quite a pain. I was happy when I first saw that the remake lets you edit them whenever you're at the base, but then I realised that not having an easy way to see what everyone's wearing so you can swap them around pretty much leaves you in the same situation as the original vis-a-vis this issue.

Comment: Because of the limitations of the squad select UI, I always back out of the mission and use the View Soldiers function to prep the squad I want before starting the mission. I also try to form up the next squad after a mission completes, although my requirements might change depending on the type of mission. This saves some time and reminds me who is carrying what.

Answer (score 9):

You may like to note that with the [Enemy Within expansion](http://xcom.wikia.com/wiki/Enemy_Within) come several interface enhancements. Notably for this question, there's a "Make Items Available" button that removes all items from everyone who isn't in the current squad. The pre-mission squad view also shows all the items in everyone's pockets so you don't have to try to remember that.

The expansion is quite expensive, but I used [isthereanydeal](http://isthereanydeal.com/#/page:game/info?plain=xcomenemywithin) to watch for when it was on sale.